# Simple Perl and CGI::Ajax form validation

Tags: ajax, perl, validation, cgi

I'm trying to do a real simple setup.

1.Do checks on each field using CGI::Ajax.
2.Validate that all fields have been filled in with simple perl CGI

The thing is, when testing individually, both work, but when combined as seen in the code below I have two issues:

1.In the username and password fields I see CGI=HASH(0x228ed48) etc
2. When I push the submit button and there is an error (a field is empty), it prints an internal server error, I believe this is due to  $ajx->build_html( $cgi, \&form($error, $username, $password)); and calling the form function in this manner.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w



use CGI;
use CGI::Session qw/ -ip-match/;
use CGI::Ajax;

$cgi = new CGI;
#$session = new CGI::Session(undef, $cgi, {Directory=> '/tmp'});
my $ajx = new CGI::Ajax( 'checkuser' => \&checkuser );

#print $ajx->build_html( $cgi, \&form);




if($cgi->param("submit")) {

process(); } else { print $ajx->build_html( $cgi, \&form); }


sub checkuser 
{
my $input = shift;
my $out = $input . " is not taken";

return $out;
}


sub form {

my $error = shift;
my $username = shift;
my $password = shift;



my $html = <<HTML;
<html>
<BODY>
<form id='log' action='session.cgi' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="Submit">
<fieldset>
<legend>Login</legend>
<font color="red">$error</font>
<label for='username' >UserName*:</label>
<input type='text' name='user' id='user' value="$username" 
maxlength="50" onchange="checkuser( ['user'], ['resultdiv'] );">
<br><br>
<div id="resultdiv"></div>
<label for='password' >Password*:</label>
<input type='password' name='pd' id='pd' value="$password" maxlength="50" />
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
</fieldset>
</form>
</body></html>
HTML

return $html;


}

sub process 
{

   if(validate_form()) {
print $cgi->header;
   print <<HTML;
<body>Validated<br></body>

HTML
                        }

}

sub validate_form 
{

my $username = $cgi->param("user");
my $password = $cgi->param("pd");

my $error = "";

 $error .= "Please enter your username<br/>" if ( !$username );
    $error .= "Please specify your password<br/>" if ( !$password );

    if ( $error )
    {
 $ajx->build_html( $cgi, \&form($error, $username, $password));
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {

        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For development, `use CGI::Carp qw/fatalsToBrowser/;`. This will allow you to see the actual errors your code is producing, rather than "Internal Server Error".

**Update:** Also, your code is failing because you are misunderstanding how a callback function works.  The callback function is not called by you; it is called by the code you pass it to--in this case the module.  So you can't provide parameters, the module does.  This won't work:

```
$ajx->build_html( $cgi, \&form($error, $username, $password));
```

`build_html` wants to call the function you pass in internally, with its own parameters.

Here you are not allowing to happen.  Instead you are calling `form()` before you call `build_html()`, then passing in a scalar reference to the result.  This fails later, because `build_html` tries to use that scalar reference as a subroutine reference.

Solution: you just need to use `\&form`.  You will need another way to fill in the fields.

Also:

- Form validation is a very common task.  Mature Perl modules are available and are widely used for this (for example, [`HTML::FormFu`](http://search.cpan.org/~cfranks/HTML-FormFu-0.09010/lib/HTML/FormFu.pm) and [`Data::Formvalidator`](http://search.cpan.org/~markstos/Data-FormValidator-4.80/)).  There are also some related modules that appear to add Javascript validation ([`HTML::FormFu::ExtJS`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aFormFu%3a%3aExtJS), [`JavaScript::DataFormValidator`](http://search.cpan.org/~markstos/JavaScript-DataFormValidator-0.50/lib/JavaScript/DataFormValidator.pm)).  It is probably worth checking these out before you create your own.
- Most modern Perl web development is done using a web framework of some sort.  The available frameworks are very powerful and worth using for all but the simplest projects.  If your goal is to learn, I recommend starting with a framework as early as possible, because development using a framework is quite different from traditional CGI development, and there is a learning curve.  I am quite happy with [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/), and there are other options as well, such as [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us/) and [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/).

Comment: Hello Dan,
Thanks for your detailed reply. I used the fatals to browser, however I got the internal server error again. Anyway, what puzzles me is the initial call to that script, $username and $password are not defined and should be '', they aren't even passed to the form() function, yet they're these weird values. About the parameters to the form function, you are probably right. And also I'll look into these web frameworks that you mentioned. Seems that there is really no point developing CGI like this.

Comment: @Sla, I thought about it more and updated the answer with what I think is happening.  The reason you are getting the weird values is because `build_html`, supplies parameters when it calls your function.

Comment: Yes, I was suspecting this was the case here. Still I'm not sure if I understand why when called initially as just $ajx->build_html( $cgi, \&form); without any arguments, $username and $password assume these weird values. Another thing, about Catalyst which was indeed the one that caught my eye, can you still integrate AJAX as easily as when using CGI::Ajax, might be a silly question, but I'll be getting the book on Catalyst. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sla, `&form` is not called "without any arguments".  It is called with whatever arguments `build_html` decides to use when calling it.  As for Catalyst, yes, there is Ajax support (though I haven't used that personally).